# Equation solving: Solve returns a periodic solution

Tags: equation-solving

I have a very simple trigonometric equation, that I've been trying to solve for a variable for a few hours now: (I couldn't find how to correctly format this)

```
sol = Solve[{
 nOut/nIn == Sin[c]/Sin[b],(*Refraction on entering*)
 nIn > 0, nOut > 0, 0 < b < π/2
 }, {c}, {}, Reals]
```

I'm trying to get `c` as a function of `b`, `nIn` and `nOut`. The output `Solve` gives me for the above code is:

```
{{c -> ConditionalExpression[π - ArcSin[(nOut Sin[b])/nIn] + 2 π C[1],
      C[1] ∈ Integers && 0 < b < π/2 && 0 < nOut <= nIn Csc[b] && nIn > 0]},
 {c -> ConditionalExpression[ArcSin[(nOut Sin[b])/nIn] + 2 π C[1], 
      C[1] ∈ Integers && 0 < b < π/2 && 0 < nOut <= nIn Csc[b] && nIn > 0]}}
```

The way I understand this is: This is a periodic answer where C[1] represents any Integer. Is that correct? **Why am I getting a periodic answer** instead of the normal single answer for inverse trig functions? How do I get this to return a non periodic answer? I'm trying to achieve:

```
c == ArcSin[Sin[b] nIn/nOut]
```

Comment: Try adding a condition `0< c < Pi/2` if this is what you're after.

Comment: b.gatessucks: Adding that gives me one ConditionalExpression, but now without the repetition. Is it ok to use this like a normal equation later on?

Comment: You can use an additional `Simplify[..., Assumptions->{...}]`.