# Using constraints when solving a trigometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I'm trying to learn how to add constraints/assumptions to equations when using `Solve`, sp as to avoid multi-valued solutions. For example, I'm trying to use Mathematica 11.3 to solve the equation

```
n Sin[theta] == Sin[alpha]
```

for `theta`, where I know `n > 1` and that the solution is in the first quadrant; i.e., `0 < theta < Pi/2`).

I tried

```
Solve[{n Sin[theta] == Sin[alpha], alpha > 0, alpha < π/4, θ > 0, θ < π/2}, theta]
```

and got the solution:

```
{{theta -> 
   Conditional
    Expression[π - ArcSin[Sin[alpha]/n] + 2 π C[1], 
    C[1] ∈ Integers && 0 < alpha < π/4 && 0 < θ < π/2]}, 
 {theta -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
     ArcSin[Sin[alpha]/n] + 2 π C[1], 
     C[1] ∈ Integers && 0 < alpha < π/4 && 0 < θ < π/2]}}
```

which seems needlessly complex to me. I tried to simplify this solution, as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73001/equation-solving-solve-returns-a-periodic-solution): but it didn't simplify. I was hoping it would reduce to

```
ArcSin[Sin[alpha]/n]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `θ` is not the same as `theta`. Fixing that, and also adding your constraint on `n`:

```
Solve[
  {n Sin[theta] == Sin[alpha], alpha > 0, alpha < π/4, theta > 0, theta < π/2, n > 1}, 
  theta]
```

yields

> ```
> {{theta -> ConditionalExpression[ArcSin[Sin[alpha]/n], 0 < alpha < π/4 && n > 1]}}
> ```

Comment: `Assuming[assume =0 < alpha < Pi/4 && 0 < theta < Pi/2 && n > 1, 
  Solve[n Sin[theta] == Sin[alpha] && assume, theta] // Simplify][[1]]`